# Dynamic Module loading scope in Python

Tags: python, dynamic, module, scope

When I run the following sample:

```
def a():
    exec('import math')
    b()

def b():
    print math.cos(90)

a()
```

I get the following error:
**NameError: global name 'math' is not defined**

What I am trying to do is to dynamically load some modules from within the a() function 
and use them in function b()

I want it to be as seamless as possible for the b()'s point of view. That means, I don't want to load the module with _ _ import _ _ in a() and pass a reference to the b() function, in fact it is mandatory that the b()'s function signature remains just this: b()

is there any way to do this guys?
thanks!

Comment: Why don't you just `import math` at the top of the file that contains `b()`?

Comment: Hmm... I'm not asking "Why?". Maybe `globals()['math'] = __import__("math")`? Looks ugly :)

Comment: because I don't know beforehand that I want to use the math module. "math" is just en example here. I want to load any module during runtime from within the a() function

Comment: @khachik: how can I vote for you or something ? total stackoverflow noob here

Comment: @Alexandros I made it an answer, with some more comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon comments on the post: if want to load modules runtime, load where you need it:

```
def b():
  m = __import__("math")
  return m.abs(-1)
```

Answering to your question:

```
def a():
  if not globals().has_key('math'):
    globals()['math'] = __import__('math')

def b():
  """returns the absolute value of -1, a() must be called before to load necessary modules"""
  return math.abs(-1)
```

Comment: why `m = __import("math")`  and not just `import math as m`?

Comment: this is what I was looking for thanks - whenever I get points I'll vote this

Comment: @aaronasterling because I came to that after putting to the `globals()` in `a`, nothing special.

Comment: @Alexandros how about accepting it? Or any other answers you consider correct.

Answer (score 2):

One approach for Python 2.x would be:

```
def a():
    exec 'import math' in globals()
    b()

def b():
    print math.cos(90)

a()
```

But I would generally recommend using `__import__()`.  I don't know what you are actually trying to achieve, but maybe this works for you:

```
def a():
    global hurz
    hurz = __import__("math")
    b()

def b():
    print hurz.cos(90)

a()
```

Comment: this as well is a great answer